# How to define a check constraint with OR condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I just want to restrict values in player_position when inserting data in the table.

```
Create Table PLAYERS
(Player_Id NUMBER(4),Player_First_Name VARCHAR(15),Player_Last_Name VARCHAR(15),Player_Team_Code CHAR(3),
Player_Position CHAR(2),
CONSTRAINT Player_Position_check CHECK (Player_position = 'QB' or 'RB' or 'WR' or 'DB' or 'LB' or 'OT' or 'DT' or 'PT' or 'KI')
CONSTRAINT Player_Id_PK PRIMARY KEY (Player_Id));
```

what is wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the proper list syntax, which is an IN cluase:

```
Create Table PLAYERS (
    Player_Id NUMBER(4),
    Player_First_Name VARCHAR(15),
    Player_Last_Name VARCHAR(15),
    Player_Team_Code CHAR(3), 
    Player_Position CHAR(2), 
    CONSTRAINT Player_Position_check 
       CHECK (Player_position in ( 'QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'DB', 'LB', 'OT', 'DT', 'PT', 'KI')),
    CONSTRAINT Player_Id_PK PRIMARY KEY (Player_Id)
);
```

You should consider whether you ought to put those values in a lookup table and define a foreign key instead.  It might not be necessary in this specific case but generally having lots of values in a check constraint is a design smell.